# Pagination for custom php code

Tags: custom-post-types, php, pagination

[This page](http://sortemaniasudoeste.com.br/resultados/) (body only) is made completely in a custom php code, based on a custom type created by Pods module.
I would like to know if there is any module that can help me insert a paging control directly inside my php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$pod = pods( 'my_pod' );

$params = array( 'limit' => 15 );

$pod->find( $params );

// Advanced Pagination
echo $pod->pagination( array( 'type' => 'advanced' ) );

// Simple Pagination
echo $pod->pagination( array( 'type' => 'simple' ) );

// Paginate
echo $pod->pagination( array( 'type' => 'paginate' ) ); 
?>
```

From [Pods documentation](https://pods.io/docs/code/pods/pagination/).